# Can I SQL Compare Local DB to VPN and Remote Desktop DB

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I am not sure this is possible, it would save a lot of time.  I can log in to a server at a client site via VPN and then Remote Desktop.  In Visual Studio there is a Schema Compare as well as a Data Compare.  I have tried MachineName\SQLServerName and a few other permutations and none seem to work.

Is this possible?
Via VS or any other (ideally free) compare tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem with the port. SQL can run in an specific port that is not the default port,

> 1433

. It can also be blocked by the vpn firewall.

You should  ask an administrator to tell you the port that the sql server is using to run and open this specific/default port for you.

Maybe you will need to open an ssh to redirect therse ports.

Then you can try to access the machine like this:

ipMachineName,port

MachineName,port
and you will be able to use any schema comparer

{1} https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287932